# How do you order countries in CountryDropDownfield in SilverStripe?

Tags: php, silverstripe

The default order of a dropdown menu generated by [`CountryDropdownField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/master/class-CountryDropdownField.html) in SilverStripe is alphabetical:

- Afghanistan
- Aland Islands
- Albania
- Algeria
- etc.

How can the dropdown be ordered so common countries are at the top of the list, followed by an alphabetical list of lesser used countries?

i.e.

- Australia
- Canada
- France
- Germany
- New Zealand
- South Africa
- United Kingdom
- United States
- Afghanistan
- Aland Islands
- Albania
- Algeria

Answer (score 4):

We can create our own array of countries and use the `CountryDropdownField` `setSource` function to set the order of the countries:

```
$countriesList = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('territory', i18n::get_locale(), 2);
asort($countriesList, SORT_LOCALE_STRING);

$commonCountries = array(
    'AU' => 'Australia',
    'CA' => 'Canada',
    'FR' => 'France',
    'DE' => 'Germany',
    'NZ' => 'New Zealand',
    'ZA' => 'South Africa',
    'GB' => 'United Kingdom',
    'US' => 'United States'
);

CountryDropdownField::create('Country', 'Country')
    ->setSource(array_merge($commonCountries, $countriesList));
```

Or using `uksort` instead of merging the arrays:

```
$countriesList = Zend_Locale::getTranslationList('territory', i18n::get_locale(), 2);
$commonCountries = array('AU', 'CA', 'FR', 'DE', 'NZ', 'ZA', 'GB', 'US');

uksort($countriesList, function ($a, $b) use ($countriesList, $commonCountries) {
    if (in_array($a, $commonCountries)) {
        if (in_array($b, $firstCountries)) {
            return ($countriesList[$a] < $countriesList[$b]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    if (in_array($b, $commonCountries)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return ($countriesList[$a] < $countriesList[$b]) ? -1 : 1;
});

CountryDropdownField::create('Country', 'Country')->setSource($countriesList);
```